# Previous Month, Next Month and Month ,Year are not working in Calendar PHP

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, calendar

I am trying to build a custom calendar with events on my website(Wordpress). I am able to get events and everything and the below code worked for a current year on localhost, however, it is not working with the live site. But the selection of month, the year is not working even on localhost. Please help me solve this issue:

PHP:

```
function draw_calendar($month,$year,$events = array()){

    /* draw table */
    $calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

    /* table headings */
    $headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

    /* days and weeks vars now ... */
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 0;
    $dates_array = array();

    /* row for week one */
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

    /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
        $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;

    /* keep going with days.... */
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;">';
            /* add in the day number */
            /* add in the day number */
                if($list_day < 10) {
                    $list_day = str_pad($list_day, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                }
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';


            $event_day = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day;
            if(isset($events[$event_day])) {
                foreach($events[$event_day] as $event) {
                    $calendar.= '<div class="event" style="background:yellow">'.'Couple-'.$event['title'].'</br>Wedding_id-'.$event['id'].'</br>Email-'.$event['email'].'</div>';
                }
            }
            else {
                $calendar.= str_repeat('<p>&nbsp;</p>',2);
            }
        $calendar.= '</div></td>';
        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</tr>';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;

    /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
    if($days_in_this_week < 8):
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
        endfor;
    endif;

    /* final row */
    $calendar.= '</tr>';


    /* end the table */
    $calendar.= '</table>';

    /** DEBUG **/
    $calendar = str_replace('</td>','</td>'."\n",$calendar);
    $calendar = str_replace('</tr>','</tr>'."\n",$calendar);

    /* all done, return result */
    return $calendar;
}

 /* date settings */
if(empty($_GET['month']) || empty($_GET['year'])) {
    $month = date('m');
    $year = date('Y');
}
else {

$month = (int) ($_GET['month'] ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
$year = (int)  ($_GET['year'] ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));}


/* select month control */
$select_month_control = '<select name="month" id="month">';
for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
  $select_month_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $month ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,$year)).'</option>';
}
$select_month_control.= '</select>';

/* select year control */
$year_range = 7;
$select_year_control = '<select name="year" id="year">';
for($x = ($year-floor($year_range/2)); $x <= ($year+floor($year_range/2)); $x++) {
  $select_year_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $year ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.$x.'</option>';
}
$select_year_control.= '</select>';

/* "next month" control */
$next_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 12 ? $month + 1 : 1).'&year='.($month != 12 ? $year : $year + 1).'" class="control" style="color:black;background:white;">Next Month &gt;&gt;</a>';

/* "previous month" control */
$previous_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 1 ? $month - 1 : 12).'&year='.($month != 1 ? $year : $year - 1).'" class="control" style="color:black;background:white;">&lt;&lt;  Previous Month</a>';


/* bringing the controls together */
$controls = '<form method="get">'.$select_month_control.$select_year_control.'&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$previous_month_link.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$next_month_link.' </form>';

/* get all events for the given month */
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'contract';
$table_name1 = $wpdb->prefix . 'wedding';
$month = str_pad($month,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $events = array();
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT c.cname AS title,c.id AS id,c.email as email, DATE_FORMAT(w.wdate,'%Y-%m-%d') AS event_date FROM $table_name c,$table_name1 w WHERE w.wdate LIKE '$year-$month%' and w.id=c.wedding_id",ARRAY_A);
 foreach ( $results as $row ) {
 $events[$row['event_date']][] = $row;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="primary" class=" col-xs-12 col-md-8" >
    <div id="calendar_div" style="padding:20px">
        <?php 
echo '<h2 style="float:left; padding-right:30px;color:black;background:white;">'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)).' '.$year.'</h2>';
echo '<div style="float:left;">'.$controls.'</div>';
echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
echo draw_calendar($month,$year,$events);
echo '<br /><br />';?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you checked your result on `date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));`

Comment: Yes, the calendar is giving input for the current month and visible on the front end. So, it is showing days for the current month of the current year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found a solution myself, I would like to post an answer which might help somebody else who is in this circumstance. However, I have used Custom session in WordPress, which is not possibly the best or recommended way to go about it but the site is internal and does not require usage beyond few employees, I decided to take this route.

The Problem is that Wordpress doesn't allow the use of Year in URL and that was interfering with my Overall Work:

Here is the code:
PHP:

```
function draw_calendar($calmonth,$calyear,$events = array()){


    /* draw table */
    $calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

    /* table headings */
    $headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

    /* days and weeks vars now ... */
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$calmonth,1,$calyear));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$calmonth,1,$calyear));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 0;
    $dates_array = array();

    /* row for week one */
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

    /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
        $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;

    /* keep going with days.... */
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;">';
            /* add in the day number */
            /* add in the day number */
                if($list_day < 10) {
                    $list_day = str_pad($list_day, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                }
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';


            $event_day = $calyear.'-'.$calmonth.'-'.$list_day;
            if(isset($events[$event_day])) {
                foreach($events[$event_day] as $event) {
                    $calendar.= '<div class="event" style="background:yellow">'.'Couple-'.$event['title'].'</br>Wedding_id-'.$event['id'].'</br>Email-'.$event['email'].'</div>';
                }
            }
            else {
                $calendar.= str_repeat('<p>&nbsp;</p>',2);
            }
        $calendar.= '</div></td>';
        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</tr>';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;

    /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
    if($days_in_this_week < 8):
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
        endfor;
    endif;

    /* final row */
    $calendar.= '</tr>';


    /* end the table */
    $calendar.= '</table>';

    /** DEBUG **/
    $calendar = str_replace('</td>','</td>'."\n",$calendar);
    $calendar = str_replace('</tr>','</tr>'."\n",$calendar);

    /* all done, return result */
    return $calendar;

}

/*Getting the Date */

if (empty($_GET['calmonth']) ||empty($_GET['calyear']) ){
   $calmonth = date('m');
    $calyear = date('Y');}

    else {
    $_SESSION['calmonth'] = $_GET['calmonth'];
    $_SESSION['calyear'] = $_GET['calyear'];
    $calmonth = $_SESSION['calmonth'];
     $calyear = $_SESSION['calyear'];}


/* select month control */
$select_month_control = '<select name="calmonth" id="calmonth">';
for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
  $select_month_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $calmonth ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,$calyear)).'</option>';
}
$select_month_control.= '</select>';

/* select year control */
$year_range = 7;
$select_year_control = '<select name="calyear" id="calyear">';
for($x = ($calyear-floor($year_range/2)); $x <= ($calyear+floor($year_range/2)); $x++) {
  $select_year_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $calyear ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.$x.'</option>';
}
$select_year_control.= '</select>';



 /* "next month" control */
$next_month_link = '<a href="?calmonth='.($calmonth != 12 ? $calmonth + 1 : 1).'&calyear='.($calmonth != 12 ? $calyear : $calyear + 1).'" class="control" style="color:black;background:white;">Next Month &gt;&gt;</a>';

/* "previous month" control */
$previous_month_link = '<a href="?calmonth='.($calmonth != 1 ? $calmonth - 1 : 12).'&calyear='.($calmonth != 1 ? $calyear : $calyear - 1).'" class="control" style="color:black;background:white;">&lt;&lt;  Previous Month</a>';  

/* bringing the controls together */
$controls = '<form method="get">'.$select_month_control.$select_year_control.'&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$previous_month_link.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$next_month_link.' </form>';

/* get all events for the given month */
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'contract';
$table_name1 = $wpdb->prefix . 'wedding';
$calmonth = str_pad($calmonth,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $events = array();
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT c.cname AS title,c.id AS id,c.email as email, DATE_FORMAT(w.wdate,'%Y-%m-%d') AS event_date FROM $table_name c,$table_name1 w WHERE w.wdate LIKE '$calyear-$calmonth%' and w.id=c.wedding_id",ARRAY_A);
 foreach ( $results as $row ) {
 $events[$row['event_date']][] = $row;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="primary" class=" col-xs-12 col-md-8" >
    <div id="calendar_div" style="padding:20px">
        <?php 
echo '<h2 style="float:left; padding-right:30px;color:black;background:white;">'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$calmonth,1,$calyear)).' '.$calyear.'</h2>';
echo '<div style="float:left;">'.$controls.'</div>';
echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
echo draw_calendar($calmonth,$calyear,$events);

echo '<br /><br />';?>
    </div>
  </div>
```